# Converting SQL to LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq

Hi I'm new to LINQ and got a requirement to convert below SQL into LINQ. 
Can someone help me how to write it?

```
select emp.id, emp.name from employee emp
left join department dept on dept.id = emp.deptid 
and (emp.managerid = '001' or (emp.manager in (select managerid from manager where location Contains('l001','l002','l003') and state =1)))
```

Thanks

Comment: what would this query expected to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var locationIds = new List<string> {"l001", "l002", "l003"};
var ls=(
    from emp in db.employee
    from dept in db.department
        .Where(a=>a.id == emp.deptid).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where (emp.managerid == "001" 
        || db.manager.Where(w=>locationIds.Contains(w.location) && w.state == 1)
                     .Select(s=>s.managerid).Contains(emp.manager))
    select new
        {
            emp.id, 
            emp.name
        }
).ToList();
```

Where db is the linq data context

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. Just I've small change in the query. instead of comparing with one string, I want to use contains. How can I do this? I've updated my post.

Comment: Update the answer. Have a look